# Backbone fetch() do not reset collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a feeling that I am doing this very badly.  I want to fetch and merge models from my server via my Backbone Collection.  I have subclassed fetch in my collection to add some custom logic for this particular collection.

```
     fetch: function (options) {
        var opts = options || {};
        this.url = this.makeURL(opts);

        if (opts.reset) {
            this.refresh();
        } else if (this.finished) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.models.length && this.models[0].get("model_id")) {
            opts["remove"] = false;
            opts["merge"] = true;
        }

        opts["data"] = opts["data"] || {};
        opts["data"]["page"] = this.page;
        opts["data"]["status"] = opts.statusChange;
        opts["data"]["tags"] = opts.tags;
        opts["success"] = _.bind(this.triggerFetched, this);
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, opts);
    },
```

it is at `if (this.models.length && this.models[0].get("model_id"))` where I feel that I am doing something very badly.

My collection was resetting on all fetches, so I looked into the backbone code and it appeared that I had to set `remove=false` in my fetch options.  The backbone documentation online seems to suggest that I can either set `add=true`or `reset=false` to the fetch options to prevent the collection from resetting.  For some reason, only setting remove to false seems to work for me, not sure if this is because of subclassing.

I am checking for the attr model_id, because it seems that Collections call fetch initially on their own when initialized and set some sort of object (I believe another collection) as it's first model initially.  It's strange and I've found that looking for one of the models that I've explicitly added like this fixes the problem.

I'm also not sure if I should set merge to true explicitly or not.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `idAttribute` set on the backbone Model. Backbone does a smart update based on the id of the model. If that is not present it would explicitly call reset every single time

Comment: Not explicitly.var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});  Could it be that I am returning an ID from my server, which is then being set?

Comment: Ok I've seen elsewhere that setting idAttribute enables merging. I have subsequently added it to no avail

Comment: Newer versions of Backbone don't reset collections on fetch unless you explicitly ask for it. Is upgrading an option?

Comment: @muistooshort.. Good point .. forgot to mention that

Comment: I am using 1.0.0, which is the latest prod release unless I'm mistaken.  So is my code then not horrible?